# Teamcity add new build agents to all builds in a project with python

Tags: python, automation, scripting, teamcity

Teamcity add new build agents to all builds in a project with python

Currently I am manually doing this by adding the hostname to the agent requirements and would like your help to automate

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding "agent requirements" by host name, you can use any one of these determined agent parameters by simply starting to type "python" and seeing the suggestions:

[image]

I would suggest `python3.version` == `exists` as a baseline, as obviously, python2 is deprecated.